# Why am I not getting all the bytes of the image in the server?

Tags: ios, c, tcp, server, stream

I am building an iOS app that takes a photo and sends it to a TCP server running on my computer. The way I'm doing it is configuring the connection with Streams like this:

```
func setupCommunication() {
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
        "192.168.1.40" as CFString, 2323, &readStream, &writeStream)

    outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
    outputStream.open()
}
```

Then, when I press the camera button, the photo is taken and sent through the outputStream. Since the TCP server doesn't know how much data it has to read, the first 8 bytes correspond to the size of the image, and the image is sent right after, as we can see in this code:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
    didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    if let image = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        print(image)
        print(image.count)

        var nBytes = UInt64(image.count)
        let nData = Data(bytes: &nBytes, count: 8)
        _ = nData.withUnsafeBytes({
            outputStream.write($0, maxLength: nData.count)
        })

        _ = image.withUnsafeBytes({
            outputStream.write($0, maxLength: image.count)
        })

        outputStream.close()
    }
}
```

On the server side, which is written in C, I perform the next actions:

Read first 8 bytes to know the size of the image

```
printf("\n[*] New client connected\n");

while (n_recv < sizeof(uint64_t)) {
    if ((n = read(client_sd, buffer, BUF_SIZ)) == -1) {
        printf("\n[-] Error reading data from the client\n");
        close(client_sd);
        close(server_sd);
        return 0;
    }

    n_recv += n;
}

memcpy(&img_size, buffer, sizeof(uint64_t));

printf("\n[+] Client says he's going to send %llu bytes\n", img_size);
```

Allocate enough memory to store the received image, and if we already read any byte of the image next to the its size, copy it.

```
if ((img_data = (uint8_t *) malloc(img_size)) == NULL) {
    printf("\n[-] Error allocating memory for image\n");
    close(client_sd);
    close(server_sd);
    return 0;
}

n_recv -= sizeof(uint64_t);
if (n_recv > 0) {
    memcpy(img_data, buffer, n_recv);
}
```

From now on, n_recv is the number of bytes received of the image only, not including the first 8 bytes for the size. Then just read till the end.

```
while (n_recv < img_size) {
    if ((n = read(client_sd, buffer, BUF_SIZ)) == -1) {
        printf("\n[-] Error reading data from the client\n");
        close(client_sd);
        close(server_sd);
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(img_data + n_recv, buffer, n);
    n_recv += n;
}

printf("\n[+] Data correctly recived from client\n");

close(client_sd);
close(server_sd);
```

This works pretty nice at the beginning. In fact, I can see that I'm getting the right number for the image size every time:

[image]

However, I'm not getting the full image, and the server just keeps waiting blocked in the read function. To see what's happening, I added this

```
printf("%llu\n", n_recv);
```

inside the loop for reading the image, to watch the number of bytes received. It stops in the middle of the image, for some reason I'm not able to explain:

[image]

What's the problem that is causing the communication to stop? Is the problem in the server code or is it something related to iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the C code looks okay to me.. but you realize you are missing return code/result handling in Swift?

In the C code you are checking the return value of `recv` to know if the bytes were read.. IE: You are checking if `read` returns -1..

However, in the swift code you make the assumption that ALL the data was written.. You never checked the result of the `write` operation on `OutputStream` which tells you how many bytes were written or returns -1 on failure..

You should be doing the same thing (after all, you did it in C).. For such cases I created two extensions:

```
extension InputStream {
    /**
     * Reads from the stream into a data buffer.
     * Returns the count of the amount of bytes read from the stream.
     * Returns -1 if reading fails or an error has occurred on the stream.
     **/
    func read(data: inout Data) -> Int {
        let bufferSize = 1024
        var totalBytesRead = 0

        while true {
            let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: bufferSize)
            let count = read(buffer, maxLength: bufferSize)
            if count == 0 {
                return totalBytesRead
            }

            if count == -1 {
                if let streamError = self.streamError {
                    debugPrint("Stream Error: \(String(describing: streamError))")
                }
                return -1
            }

            data.append(buffer, count: count)
            totalBytesRead += count
        }
        return totalBytesRead
    }
}

extension OutputStream {
    /**
     * Writes from a buffer into the stream.
     * Returns the count of the amount of bytes written to the stream.
     * Returns -1 if writing fails or an error has occurred on the stream.
     **/
    func write(data: Data) -> Int {
        var bytesRemaining = data.count
        var bytesWritten = 0

        while bytesRemaining > 0 {
            let count = data.withUnsafeBytes {
                self.write($0.advanced(by: bytesWritten), maxLength: bytesRemaining)
            }

            if count == 0 {
                return bytesWritten
            }

            if count < 0 {
                if let streamError = self.streamError {
                    debugPrint("Stream Error: \(String(describing: streamError))")
                }
                return -1
            }

            bytesRemaining -= count
            bytesWritten += count
        }

        return bytesWritten
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

//For testing I used 127.0.0.1
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, "192.168.1.40" as CFString, 2323, &readStream, &writeStream)


//Actually not sure if these need to be retained or unretained might be fine..
//Again, not sure..
var inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue() as InputStream
var outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue() as OutputStream

inputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)
outputStream.schedule(in: .current, forMode: .common)

inputStream.open()
outputStream.open()


var dataToWrite = Data() //Your Image
var dataRead = Data(capacity: 256) //Server response -- Pre-Allocate something large enough that you "think" you might read..

outputStream.write(data: dataToWrite)
inputStream.read(data: &dataRead)
```

Now you get error handling (printing) and you have buffered reading/writing.. After all, you're not guaranteed that the socket or pipe or w/e.. the stream is attached to has read/written ALL your bytes at once.. hence the reading/writing chunks.

Comment: Thank you! It worked nice :) By the way, do you know how can I learn more about networking with iOS and Swift?